# Stacked 100% barplots

Tags: r, data-visualization

I would like to visualise proportions of quantities like:

```
Four values are votes for great/good/moderate/bad
data1 <- c(4, 6, 0, 1)
data2 <- c(2, 0, 1, 15)
```

using R as stacked horizontal barplots where each of the two bars `data1` and `data2` is whole width of the chart and great / good / moderate / bad are in different colours / patterns, like:

```
XXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOO%%

XX*%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

I am using lots of other charts in R (besides automation, another reason to use it!), but I can't get the grasp how to do this one.

Comment: for the pattern you can do `x <- c('X' = 2, 'O' = 0, '*' = 1, '%' = 15); paste(strrep(names(x), x), collapse = '')` although I'm not sure why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
dat <-data.frame(data1,data2)

barplot(prop.table(as.matrix(dat), margin = 2), horiz  = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, works nicely! But shouldn't it be dat <-data.frame(data1,data2)?

Comment: I wonder how this would change if data1/data2 would not be available of counts of great/good/... votes but as encoded values: c(1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1) (1= great, 2 = good, ...)

Comment: @LeRookie my apologies, I used a library in the answer that was not loaded. `data.frame` works, I will edit

Answer (score 3):

Here's a `ggplot2` answer:

```
library(ggplot2)
data1 <- c(4, 6, 0, 1)
data2 <- c(2, 0, 1, 15)

MyData <- data.frame(DataSource= c(rep("data1",4),rep("data2",4)),
                     quality=rep(c("great","good","moderate","bad"),2),
                     Value=c(data1/sum(data1),data2/sum(data2)))

ggplot(data=MyData,aes(DataSource,Value,fill=quality))+geom_col()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can point you in the right direction:

```
data1 <- c(4, 6, 0, 1)
data2 <- c(2, 0, 1, 15)
data3 <- c("great","good","moderate","bad")

df <- data.frame(group1 = data1,group2 = data2, class = data3)

library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df<- melt(df,"class")
df <- df %>% group_by(variable) %>% mutate(perc = value/sum(value))
ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = perc,fill=class)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') + coord_flip()
```

[image]